# Some space, even when the padding and margin are set to 0px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
body{
 background: #f2f2f2;
 font-family: Metrophobic, Arial, serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#nav{
 width:60%;
 margin:auto;
}
#topnav{
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 background: #009688;
 display: block;
}
a{
 margin: 0px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
a:visited{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #f2f2f2;
}
#navl{
 float:left;
}
#navr{ 
 float:right;
}
#nav ul li{
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
#nav img{
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>First Project</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link src="java.js" type="text/script">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="topnav">

   <div id="nav">
    <div id="navl">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="navr">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

There seems to be space on the left of each div tags.

Comment: you css post it maybe it has something to do with it

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: You need to post the style.css.  It looks like you're using a css menu that is floating the div tags.  Div tags are normally surrounded by line breaks so you shouldn't even notice "spaces to their left.

Comment: I've just added the css. If you inspect element, the <li>Home is shifted to right b around 15px. How to get rid of it?

Comment: @howdyauthor The `body` is the culprit. See [@Shailesh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32665636/3049655) to know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you also include a screenshot of what the problem is?  I tried to do a mockup but honestly I don't see what space you are trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 2):

```
body{
   background: #f2f2f2;
   font-family: Metrophobic, Arial, serif;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: You need to post a screenshot of what you are trying to get rid of.  I can't replicate any "space" that are "left of each div tags".

Answer (score 1):

in css:

```
div {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

should eliminate the space between them

Comment: How can you suggest this answer without seeing the style.css?  This doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I've just added the css

Answer (score 0):

```
ul, label {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Default css values were the problems.